# Set theory: proving of set identities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have four sets A, B, C and X.

How can one prove the following identity:

> $(A \cap B \cap C \cap  \neg X) \cup ( \neg A \cap C) \cup ( \neg B \cap C) \cup (C \cap X)=C$

I tried to apply here any of basic set identities like `Distributive Law` or `Associative Law` but it led me to nothing.

Any help would be appreciated, then.

Comment: Can't you just prove it by showing that if $x \in C$, then $x \in $LHS, and vice-versa? It looks like you could use DeMorgan's laws, but this might just be shorter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prahlad Vaidyanathan’s suggestion in the comments is probably the easiest way to go, but an algebraic proof is certainly possible. First note that $$(\neg A\cap C)\cup(\neg B\cap C)=(\neg A\cup\neg B)\cap C$$ by one of the distributive laws. Then $C\cap X=X\cap C$, and

$$\big((\neg A\cup\neg B)\cap C\big)\cup(X\cap C)=\big(\neg A\cup\neg B\cup X\big)\cap C$$

by one of the distributive laws. Thus, the original lefthand side is equal to

$$(A\cap B\cap C\cap\neg X)\cup\big((\neg A\cup\neg B\cup X)\cap C\big)\;.\tag{1}$$

Now use one of the De Morgan laws and the fact that $\neg(\neg Y)=Y$ to see that

$$\neg A\cup\neg B\cup X=\neg(A\cap B\cap\neg X)\;,$$

so that $(1)$ is equal to

$$\Big((A\cap B\cap\neg X)\cap C\Big)\cup\Big(\neg(A\cap B\cap\neg X)\cap C\Big)\;,$$

and use a distributive law to pull out the $C$ and get

$$\Big((A\cap B\cap\neg X)\cup\neg(A\cap B\cap\neg X)\Big)\cap C\;.\tag{2}$$

Finally, use the fact that $Y\cup\neg Y$ is the universal set, which I’ll call $U$, so that $(2)$ is $$U\cap C=C\;.$$

Comment: Just one question. How many examples must I solve to start easily decompose such identities to simple parts according to set identities laws? I didn't see all those parts, until you showed them :(

Comment: @Dragon: That seems to vary enormously from one person to another. I can tell you some of what went through my mind, if that helps: every term on the lefthand side included an intersection with $C$, so in principle I could have factored $C$ out and got $$\text{ugly expression}\cap C\;.$$ This equals $C$ if and only if $\text{ugly expression}\supseteq C$. Instead of trying to deal with this all at once, I did it in smaller, simpler chunks: I just kept pulling out $C$ and combining what was left, starting with the simplest bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I need more practice for sure.

Comment: @Dragon: You’re welcome.

Comment: My version, explaining _why_ each step is done:
$\newcommand{\s}[2]{\\#1\quad&\quad\text{"#2"}\\\quad&}$
\begin{align}\quad&
(A\cap B\cap C\cap\neg X)\cup(\neg A\cap C)\cup(\neg B\cap C)\cup(C\cap X)
\s={$\cap$ is symmetric, twice; $\cap$ distributes over $\cup$ -- to factor out the ${}\cap C$ part}
((A\cap B\cap\neg X)\cup\neg A\cup\neg B\cup X)\cap C
\s={DeMorgan -- to make the left hand part more symmetrical}
((A\cap B\cap\neg X)\cup\neg(A\cap B\cap\neg X))\cap C
\s={simplify: a set and its complement cover the universe $U$}
U\cap C
\s={simplify: $U$ is the identity of $\cap$}
C
\end{align}